# how to distinguish day/night with [NSDate date]?

Tags: iphone

after i get current device time by using [NSDate date], how do i know it's daytime or night now?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the backtick character (`) either side of in-line code to format it nicely ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be absolutely certain, I'd use a weather API like Yahoo's weather.  Send the current location to the API, and you'll get back some data that contains the sunset and sunrise times for that area.

If the current time is past the sunset time... blammo.